# SQL Server 2008 job failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, jobs

I have a problem on my servers sitting on different domains.

I created a linked server that executes successfully and I can list the catalogue but when I schedule a job to execute I get this error:

> Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How did you define the security option from the linked server SECURITY option out of the four options that should be there?

Answer (score 1):

### Condsiderations for `linked server` security options in SQL Server

***(Two things to mention for typical simple configurations)***

---

- If you have the option set to `Be made using the login's current security context` then . . .

  - ensure that the security principal (and context) that the job will `RUN AS` from the `SQL Agent`job also has appropriate access to any of the `linked server` DB(s) which the job will need to access for it's queries, etc.
  - if the security principal is a local SQL login and not a domain or trusted domain account, then be sure that the local SQL account is created with a matching SID on both the `linked server` SQL Server instance and the SQL Server instance where the job is using the linked server from.

---

- If you have the option set to `Be made using the security context:` then . . .

  - ensure the local SQL login security principal is created with a matching SID on both the `linked server` SQL Server instance and the SQL Server instance where the job is using the linked server from.

[image]